# URL 123qestion.gq points to stack overflow

Tags: discussion, security

So this site loads up stack overflow,  wondering if anyone knows if this is a potential security issue as I know stackExchange disallows being embedded in an iframe.

seems a bit worrying as its starting to show up as top search results when I'm looking around for stuff

Comment: SE meta duplicate: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177)